# Word to describe people in internet thinking very same, using same websites, reading same resources

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, internet, mass-media

Is there a term or word to describe people in internet **feeling very same**, like if they were doing absolutely **same things using internet**?

Here in the web we have too many apps and websites, but many people sometimes use same. This creates **"hubs" or "circles"** of disconnected people, but with close feelings and possibly **interests**, doing same things (like using same social network and following same public persons).

How can i call such people or their "phenomenon of thinking sameness"?

Comment: Echo chamber, although this never has positive connotations

Comment: Got it [echo chamber (media)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_(media))

Answer (score 1):

## [Like-minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likeminded)

> Having similar opinions or interests

*"A dedicated football fan herself, she started the online community for likeminded women"*

Answer (score 1):

Try [tribe or digital tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe_(Internet))

A community of people with common interests.

Comment: That was i also looking for. Unfortunately question was locked:(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ***[online/virtual community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_community)***:

> - An online community is a virtual community whose members interact with each other primarily via the Internet. ***For many, online communities may feel like home, consisting of a “family of invisible friends***."Those who wish to be a part of an online community usually have to become a member via a specific site and necessarily need an internet connection.
> - ***An online community can act as an information system where members can post, comment on discussions, give advice or collaborate***. Commonly, people communicate through social networking sites, chat rooms, forums, e-mail lists and discussion boards. People may also join online communities through video games, blogs and virtual worlds.

(Wikipedia)